# Can I tell Elasticsearch to give particular field more boost?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I'm using a simple search in Elasticsearch but I would like to give a particular url a boost so it would come up first in the search result. I'm not sure if it's possible?

Here's my mapping.

```
                "hal": {
                    "properties": {
                        "label": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "fields": {
                                "raw": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "url": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
```

And here's my query

```
{
    "fields": [ "url","brand"],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "terms": {
                    "brand": ["brand"]
                }
            },{
                "terms": {
                    "hal.label.raw": ["donald trump"]

                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I search I would get at least 500 results back. However, there's a particular pattern of `url` that I would like to give it a boost which is 
`http://www.anything.com/people/*` So any `url` with `/people` would come up first in the search result. Is this even at all possible in Elasticsearch? Otherwise I would have to get everything and filter in the code instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `should` clause that will automatically boost any matching results (make sure `url` is set to `type: string` and `index: not_analyzed`):

```
{
  "fields": [
    "url",
    "brand"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "brand": [
              "brand"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "hal.label.raw": [
              "donald trump"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "url": "http://www.anything.com/people/*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can also specify a specific boost value:

```
{
  "fields": [
    "url",
    "brand"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "brand": [
              "brand"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "hal.label.raw": [
              "donald trump"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "url": {
              "value": "http://www.anything.com/people/*",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have [regex query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) in should clause with high boost. Try the following query

```
{
  "fields": [
    "url",
    "brand"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "brand": [
              "brand"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "hal.label.raw": [
              "donald trump"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "url": "http://www.anything.com/people/.*",
            "boost" : 50
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```